# How to set the username hyperlink to open the user's EasySocial Profile in Fabrik?

Tags: component, profile, fabrik

Now I am using Fabrik and EasySocial.
[image]

Here is the table of Fabrik and the Label name "ADDED BY" is user name from Joomla User.

When I click on username, it takes me to edit the record, but I don't want it to be way. I want when someone clicks the username, for the link to open the User Profile of EasySocial.

When someone clicks the username "SOK SAVRY", the link opens this profile: `https://seekkhmer.com/index.php/profile-layout/saovry`

When someone clicks username "Khan Vannara", the link opens this profile:
`https://seekkhmer.com/index.php/profile-layout/khun-vannara`

I asked the Fabrik about this and they just told me (You can add a custom link to your "Added by" element (List view settings/List settings).

My problem is that I don't know about the custom link of EasySocial component.

Comment: Thank you for joining us Saovry.  Please take our [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your user element.
From left menu open List view settings->tab List settings.
There have a field Custom link. Read label tooltip.
Place in field your link to Easysocial user. Replace user id with {rowid}.